# VSTO splash screen excel startup

Tags: excel, vba, vsto

Using VSTO to create a document level add-in for Excel 2013, I'm trying to create a splash screen to run at startup for a few seconds (and then close).

I added the Splash Screen to my Workbook in VSTO (`Project->Add New Item`) and I can see it in the designer.

But how do I show it every time Excel starts?

This is the code I'm using in `ThisWorkbook.vb:`

```
Public Class ThisWorkbook
    Dim splash As New SplashScreen1()
    Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        splash.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that you develop an add-in, not a standalone application. Splash screens typically are used for standalone applications only. You may consider developing a standalone application which may automate Excel and load your document. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301982) to get started quickly. While the work is performed you can display a splash screen. And when the add-in is loaded (or file) you can close the application programmatically, Excel should be left running separately. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! I'm developing excel templates with VBA to interact with the user and perform certain repetitive tasks. Now, my goal is to protect the code and improve the UI with a task pane and a splash screen. I've installed VSTO 2015 and I'm trying to achieve this. However, there isn't much organised information about this and it seems that nobody is developing this kind of applications anymore since I don't get any answers to my questions in MS forums. If you know of a tutorial, course, books or whatever, I'd really appreciate, thank you!